# How can I track the time it takes for someone to fill out a Google form?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-forms, google-sheets-arrayformula

I am running a study for my thesis, and would very much like to track the time it takes to complete a Google form to compare against how long it takes to fill.

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask]. Also add more details about what kind of solution you are looking for, otherwise the question is primarily opinion-based or too broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sneaky way would be to ask the respondent to enter a current time as the first question of your form and the actual submission time will act as the end time. Then you just run a simple **`ARRAYFORMULA`** in your spreadsheet to get the duration:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A20:A), A20:A-B20:B, ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Is there any system that would automatically capture the start time do you know?

Comment: unfortunately no. this would be only workaround